# UNIX - Executing command as root with no sudo/su access

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

We don't have sudo or su access root on the unix servers we're working on.

The only way in order to 'switch' to a root user and operate under it is to issue a "goto root" command (dont ask!).

What I'm trying to do is to issue/execute a command as a root user through a single command line.

I realize that this can be done as such:

1.goto root

2."execute random command"

...however, my question is, how can I do that in a single statement? If i had sudo/su access, I would have been able to do it as such:

sudo "command"

The reason why I'm aiming at executing this on a single command line is that following:

I'm logging to the unix server remotely, im ssh-ing to the server as my own unix user. I want to to issue commands as root. If i issue 2 statements where the first one is goto root, then my second statement is executed under my own user and not root. I'm not sure if im clear regarding this, so in case anyone needs more clarifications ill be more than happy to.

Comment: the only way I can think of would be to use an `expect` script. Kind of horrible since youre going to embed the root password in the script if you do this.

Comment: did you try to `goto root visudo` and add some sudoers(5) rule? Is sudo/su technically not possible or you are obligated not to use it?

Comment: @camelccc The problem is that I don't have the root password

Comment: @MichałŠrajer I can't use sudo/su technically. Simply not available for me to use.

Comment: @Brams if you can gain a root console from a command you can use expect to execute the goto root, then wait for an appropriate response, then execute your other command(s) Its ugly, but you can automate any shell intwraction this way

Answer (score 0):

To execute them in a single line. You can pipe(|) any commands with goto root like this

```
goto root | some command
```

some command will executed with root privilege since shell does not complete the current operation.

Comment: I did try that initially, but it simply hangs. Nothing happens and I had to abort.